# Access application settings in react application deployed on Azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-settings

I have deployed react application on Azure app service and I need to access application settings from environment variable.
I have checked using kudu using following command and its showing application setting
output of-

```
node --print 'process.env'
```

but when I am trying to access that from react code the object has changed 
and process.env its showing different value.

```
console.log(process.env)
```

Thanks,
Shraddha Agrawal

Comment: can you print the object in react

Comment: env is undefined

Answer (score -1):

Append application setting key with 'REACT_APP_'.